# GPX file containing speed information

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am currently using the DDMS perspective to simulate movement of the android emulator with a gpx file.  However, I have only been able to find gpx files with lat/lon pairs in them and not with speed, altitude, etc.  Any recommendations on a place to find a good gpx file which contains the above data for emulator testing purposes?  Thanks.

Update : I've noticed that the file I am using does indeed have altitude in it, yet when I retrieve it it shows up as zero.  Only the lat/lon is showing up properly.  Can the android emulator only use the lat/lon of gpx files and not altitude?

Answer (score 9):

You do not need to search anywhere on `"Tool to download GPX"`

You can simply generate `.kml` and `.gpx` files from google maps. :)

1. Go to http://maps.google.com/
2. Click on `Get Directions` hyper-link below google logo.
3. Enter two known places from your local area or anywhere in the world, which could be reached by car that is and click on Get Directions.
4. Google will generate driving directions for you.
5. Now when you see coloured direction showing up on the map click on `Link` hyper-link on the right side of the window.
6. Copy link from `Paste link in email or IM` section and copy it to you address bar, hit enter.
7. Now to create

**.kml**

I am emphasizing this approach since it does not need any third party intervention and
can serve the purpose.

- Go to your address bar and at the end of the entire looong address type `&output=kml`
  heres an example:

  http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&source=s_d&saddr=US-41+N&daddr=1060+W+Addison+St,+Chicago,+IL+60613&hl=en&geocode=Ff6uSwIdkP3H-g;FagQgAIdAXjG-ikh35rlstMPiDFSRA7TUMlPMA&mra=dme&mrcr=0&mrsp=0&sz=6&sll=40.4225,-82.346577&sspn=8.376378,14.128418&ie=UTF8&z=6**&output=kml**

You'll be prompted to save the .kml file save it anywhere and load it to eclipse.

**.gpx**

- Perform all the steps from IE or Mozilla Firefox and add a bookmarklet or Add to favorites bar

  ```
  javascript:(function(){var     script=document.createElement('script');script.src='http://www.elsewhere.org/GMapToGPX/gmaptogpx.js';document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);})()
  ```
- Now after pasting the looooong link in the address bar click on this bookmarklet you'll be prompted with the `.gpx` file save the entire code in the text editor and save it as .gpx and your done.

You can visit http://www.elsewhere.org/journal/gmaptogpx/ for entire tutorial on how to generate .gpx.

And about your second question emulators cannot simulate altitudes.

Answer (score 1):

This is the webservice I use:

http://gpx.geotags.com/

basically does all the leg work you just type the TO/FROM and DL gpx :D

GPX 1.0 seems to be deprecated, you have to use GPX files with 1.1 version in eclipse

Comment: Does not work anymore since maps services has become non-free... Thanks Google!