# Android: How to test android speedometer

Tags: android, android-studio

I created an android speedometer and I want to test it on a device. Is there any way to test it on the Android virtual device? Or any other alternative to test it ? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load a GPX or KML file into the emulator (via the Location settings) and play it back in real time.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398834/gpx-file-containing-speed-information) for a description of how to produce a suitable file.

Answer (score 0):

An update for latest version of emulator (Apr 2021).

The emulator has the ability to create a route and play it from the emulator itself.

Go to the extended control by clicking on the three dots at the bottom:

[image]

Then choose location and you will get a Google maps interface that you can enter a location on and then type in a destination, as you would in the standard google maps app. You can then start your route.

Playback speed can be adjusted via a button on the bottom right:

[image]